# What is the difference between a SpatialGrid object and a raster object in R?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, r-sp

As far as I have gathered, both classes store data in a grid that is divided into cells of equal area, and both have coordinate reference systems.

One difference seems to be that a SpatialGrid object must be a complete rectangle, whereas a raster I think can have irregular boundaries.

When I'm deciding between them, I also think of what functions I want to use them with, as these often need a certain class as an input.

Are there any other major differences between the two that I may not be aware of? Limitations? Method of storing data? Effects on computation time for large databases?